# How to call onclick on another activity?

Tags: java, android

I just started development in android and got stuck with this idea

I have created two activity one is the HomeActivity and other one is LoginActivity. I want to put minimal code in the HomeActivity and all other operations i want to put in another activity.

My use-case is i have put an onclick event on HomeActivity and the onclick method implementation i have written in LoginActivity. But i am unable to call the LoginActivity onclick method implementation. Also, both HomeActivity and LoginActivity are having the same layout (activity_main.xml)

The files are as follows:

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

  private static String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
   }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
   private static String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
   }

  public void onLogin(View view){
     // some actions
   TextView loginText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login);
  }

  }
```

activity_home.xml

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  />
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/login_bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick = "onLogin"
   />
```

Both HomeActivity and LoginActivity are using the same layout activity_home. Is it correct and possible to do this in android.
and secondly if it's possible how to invoke onLogin on LoginActivity so that i can set the text to the TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom class `CustomActivity` that extends `Activity`

```
private class CustomActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onLogin(View view)
    {
        TextView loginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    }
}
```

and then extend `LoginActivity` and `HomeActivity` with `CustomActivity`. This way `onLogin` method will be available to both `LoginActivity` and `HomeActivity` and if you need to change what you do in `onLogin` you can override it in any of the child classes.

If you are using the above method as-is make sure that the layout of both `LoginActivity` and `HomeActivity` have a `TextView` with id `login`